# How to get number of records deleted with PHQL?

Tags: phalcon

I make query through the PHQL to delete records. How can I get the number of deleted records?

In older versions,  I used the construction

```
$this->modelsManager->getReadConnection('ModelName')->affectedRows();
```

But in new version this does not work.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Main Api  Docs](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/master/api/Phalcon_Db_Adapter_Pdo.html), You can get affected rows by this way:

```
$connection->execute("DELETE FROM robots");
echo $connection->affectedRows(), ' were deleted';
```

Try it & get your affected rows.

Good Luck